# Test route and stub a function call within it?

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, sinon, chai

Is it possible to stub a function within an Express route using Mocha and Sinon?

Here's the implementation, in `./apps/stuff/controller.js`

```
import db from '../lib/database';

const getStuff = async (req, res) => {
  const results = await db.query(req.id); // I want to stub this
  return res.status(200).json({
    thingy: results.thingy,
    stuff: [
      results.foo,
      results.bar,
    ],
  });
};

export default {
  getStuff,
};
```

And the Express route for it, in `./routes.js`

```
import stuff from './apps/stuff/controller';
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.route('/stuff')
  .get(stuff.getStuff);
```

So in the test case, I want to stub the call to `db.query()` and instead return a custom result during the `GET /stuff` request the test runs.

```
// ./test/stuff/controller.js
import db from '../../apps/lib/database';

import chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import server from '../../index';

const { expect } = chai;

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('getStuff', () => {
  it('gets you stuff', async () => {
    // I have tried this, but it results in TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property query
    // I presume it is creating a new "empty" object instead of stubbing the actual implementation
    sandbox.stub(db, 'query').resolves({ thingy: 'bar', stuff: [ 123, 'wadsofasd' ] });

    chai.request(server)
      .get('/stuff?id=123')
      .then(res => {
        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        expect(res.body).to.deep.equal({
          thingy: 'bar',
          stuff: [
            123,
            'wadsofasd',
          ]
        });
      }); 
  });
});
```

What is the correct way to stub/mock the db.query call in the above scenario? I've been searching online for hours, but haven't come across a single working version of a similar case.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative beside using proxyquire is to **Avoid using import default**

Your `db` module looks like using `export default` (it is not exported as symbol) and make sinon couldn't stub it properly.

The solution is using named export

**database.js**

```
export function query() {
 // implementation
}

=== OR ===

function query() { .. }

module.exports = {
  query
}
```

**stuff/controller.js**

```
import * as db from '../lib/database'; // alternative => import { query } from '...'

const getStuff = async (req, res) => {
  const results = await db.query(req.id); // I want to stub this
  // ...
};
```

**test/stuff/controller.js**

```
import * as db from '../../apps/lib/database';

// ...

sandbox.stub(db, 'query').resolves({ thingy: 'bar', stuff: [ 123, 'wadsofasd' ] });
```

Ref:

- https://blog.neufund.org/why-we-have-banned-default-exports-and-you-should-do-the-same-d51fdc2cf2ad
- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html (typescript but the reason still makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried `proxyquire`?

Proxyquire is a javascript library to cheat the node.js require so you can pass it a another function (your stub) when then detects require('example/route/of/your/import').

https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire

So you can write

```
    const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

    proxyquire('./apps/stuff/controller', {
        getStuff: sandbox.stub()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it later today.

Comment: OK, tell me if it went well

Comment: I am sorry for contacting you this way (my comment isnt related to your input here). I came across a question you voted on in "triage" where you made the wrong choice. Please: study the help for triage carefully, to avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. I hope you see this as a chance to improve your voting. I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21145745. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me. If you give me a quick reply, I will immediately delete this comment here.